# What WPF Panel control to use that anchors children to an edge (Concertina effect)?

Tags: wpf, controls, expression-blend, anchor, storyboard

This (hopefully) is an easy one... I'm trying to find a WPF panel that I can use that when resized keeps all it's vertically aligned children (buttons) offset the same distance from the bottom edge of the panel, so it looks like they are expanding.

The obvious one is to use a dock panel and anchor to the bottom but this doesn't seem to work. Putting more that 2 children in there messes up the alignment and whatever I do I can't get them vertically lined up. I've tried all sorts of panels but have had no joy. I'm assuming it's fairly straightforward but it's stumped me!

Basically I'm trying to get a concertina effect when I click the top button the panel expands and shows all the sub buttons. And when I click the top button again it collapses. I guess I can move each of the children with a storyboard but I have to think all my story needs to do is change the size of the panel and the children maintain their offsets and concertina out...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can actually use a Canvas and set the Canvas.Top, Left, Right, and Bottom properties of the controls to get the same effect as WinForms and anchor.

```
<Canvas>
    <Button Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Bottom="10" Content="Button 1"  Name="button1"  />
    <Button Canvas.Left="90" Canvas.Bottom="10" Content="Button 2"  Name="button2"  />
</Canvas>
```

[image]

Also Grid can do similar:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Button 1"  Name="button1" Margin="5" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Button 2"  Name="button2" Margin="5" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

If "Basically I'm trying to get a concertina effect" is the essence of your question (Am I right ?) then, did you tried tu use an built-in WPF expander ? It seems to me that you are trying to build up your own...

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite get what you mean by concertina effect, it could have to do with stretching as well. If you want anchoring you can use a Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition /> <!-- Gets all available space i.e. resizes with window -->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> <!-- Sizes to content, always stays at the bottom -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!-- Resizable content goes in Grid.Row="0" -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5">
        <Button Name="ButtonOK" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100" Margin="5" Click="ButtonOK_Click" IsDefault="True">OK</Button>
        <Button Name="ButtonCancel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100" Margin="5" Click="ButtonCancel_Click" IsCancel="True">Cancel</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```